# java automatic function calling

Tags: java

i have a math class that stores representation of expressions in n-array lists
i currently have three classes AdditionArray MultipleArray and Variable they all implement my Number interface.

```
public interface Number {

  public Number Multiply(Number number);
```

in the classes that implement Number i have overloaded opertions like Multiply for example

```
public class MultipleArray extends ArrayList<Number> implements Number{
  public Number Multiply(AdditionArray number);
  public Number Multiply(Number number){throw new Exception("woops");}
```

the thing is java is not automatically calling the correct overloaded function at runtime. it seams to be figuring it out at compile time

for example

```
Number someNumber = new MultipleArray();
Number someOtherNumber = new AdditonArray();

MultipleArray result2 = someNumber.Multiply(someOtherNumber); //calls the correct function

Number result2 = someNumber.Multiply(someOtherNumber); // throws the woops exception
```

why is java doing this. and is there another way i can implement this. some sort of factory for example?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: Just a practical advise: by convention, methods start with a lowercase, class with an uppercase letter. Greatly improves readability

Comment: yes i agree but there is a reason... for consistance. i knew i was going to be using lists. i would not be able to implement add to the list and Add the mathmatic function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bill K said, Java determines this at compile time, and this is by design.

The really standard way to implement this is to have code in the overloaded method with the supertype that checks the type of the subclass and delegates with a cast or throws an exception as appropriate.

Using Generics is another option, which will improve your type safety, but I don't know enough about your code to say if it would work all around. A generic number interface might look like this:

```
 public interface Number<T extends Number> {
       public T multiply(Number<? extends T> number);
 }
```

Generics can get weird around the edges, so it might be worth it to just give up on the type safety and go with checking the type of the parameter.

Comment: generics sounds like a good way forward! that way java would call the overrided method and work the way java is designed. am i correct?

Comment: @Mark, In very short, yes, with some potential gotchas depending on how complicated you needed to get.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, *overloading* is a type of compile-time polymorphism, while *overriding* is a type of run-time polymorphism. See [What is the difference between method overriding and method overloading in Java?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_method_overriding_and_method_overloading_in_Java).

This means that the compiler will always determine at compile time which of two overloaded methods to call, as opposed to overridden methods (which are methods with the same signature defined in the child as the ancestor class) which can be dynamically dispatched to based on the run-time type of the class on which the method is being called.

Answer (score 1):

I did not really look at your code, but just to respond to your primary question there--Java does figure out what to call at compile time based on the nearest type.  If it did it at runtime, it would be a dynamic language.

Java is amazingly fast for what it does--but it gets a lot of it's speed by not thinking as much at runtime.  It tends to be in the area of 10x faster than Python and 100x faster than Ruby.

If you want more flexibility in this, I suggest you don't use Java's bindings at all but create an "Operation" object and manually tie it to your "Numbers".  In this way you can make a pretty cool algebraic tree out of objects.  If nothing else it's fun--I've done it a few times.  It'll still be darn fast.

Comment: so your talking about a Operation factory that knows about all types of number so you would do something like
Operation.multiply(multiplyArray,additionArray)->additionArray

Comment: One way or the other, I think you are going to have to check the types of the values and branch to a different operation based on the type.

Comment: Looked at it for a bit.  I think you may find life easier if you make Multiply a class of it's own--or maybe a static method.  You will pass each operand as one of two types of Number (ScalarNumber or ArrayNumber maybe?) then examine the types to determine how to operate on them.  Implementing multiply as a member of a number class seems like it's going to be trouble.